# expected expression before '{' token

Tags: c, expression, token

I am getting: "error: expected expression before '{' token" for the line I've commented before. If the struct is already defined why would it need a "{" before token. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
struct sdram_timing {
    u32 wrdtr;
    u32 clktr;
};

int calibration(void);
unsigned char read_i2c_cal(void);
static unsigned int eepcal[15];

main() {
    DQS_autocalibration();
}

int calibration(void)
{
    struct sdram_timing scan_list[30];

    read_i2c_cal();
    if(eepcal[0] == 0){

       scan_list = {{eepcal[1], eepcal[2]}, {-1, -1}}; // <-- PROBLEM LINE

        }
        else {
            //foo
        }

    return 0;
}

unsigned char read_i2c_cal(void) {
    eepcal[0] = 0;
    eepcal[1] = 02;
    eepcal[2] = 03;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error is because you can't assign an array that way, that only works to initialize it.

```
int arr[4] = {0}; // this works
int arr2[4];

arr2 = {0};// this doesn't and will cause an error

arr2[0] = 0; // that's OK
memset(arr2, 0, 4*sizeof(int)); // that is too
```

So applying this to your specific example:

```
struct sdram_timing scan_list[30];
scan_list[0].wrdtr = 0;
scan_list[0].clktr = 0;
```

or you could use memset the same way, but instead of sizeof(int) you need size of your structure. That doesn't always work... but given your structure, it will.

Comment: so after it is initialized using "struct sdram_timing scan_list[30];" how can I assign values to scan_list?

Comment: @txcotrader - What I gave you was the generic way to do it. I edited my post to give you a specific example using your code.

Comment: This also happens when trying to assign a struct (e.g. `struct { int a; int b; } foo; foo = {1, 2};`)... +1 for differentiating assignment and initialization in a way that gave me a quick answer.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays in C language are not assignable. You can't assign anything to the entire array, regardless of what syntax you use. In other words, this

```
scan_list = { { eepcal[1], eepcal[2] }, {-1, -1} };
```

is not possible.

In C89/90 you'd have to spell out your assignments line by line

```
scan_list[0].wrdtr = eepcal[1];
scan_list[0].clktr = eepcal[2];
scan_list[1].wrdtr = -1;
scan_list[1].clktr = -1;
```

In modern C (post-C99) you can use compound literals to assign entire structs

```
scan_list[0] = (struct sdram_timing) { eepcal[1], eepcal[2] };
scan_list[1] = (struct sdram_timing) { -1, -1 };
```

Finally, in modern C you can use `memcpy` and compound literals to copy data to the array

```
memcpy(scan_list, (struct sdram_timing[]) { { eepcal[1], eepcal[2] }, {-1, -1} },
  2 * sizeof *scan_list);
```

The last variant, albeit not very elegant, is the closest way to "emulate" array assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use an initializer list in the declaration of the variable, not after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Initializer list can only be used to initialize an array. You cannot use it afterwards.

However if you use `GCC`, you can use `Compound Literal` extension:

```
scan_list = (struct sdram_timing[30]){{eepcal[1], eepcal[2]}, {-1, -1}};
```

You might need to change `scan_list` type to be `struct sdram_timing *`

Comment: Compound literals do exist in C99, but that doesn't mean that arrays are assignable in C99. They are not. Your code will not compile.

Comment: what if I want to modify values of scan_list after it is initialized?

Comment: @AndreyT I just realized. Array variables cannot stand alone as a lvalue. Need to change to a pointer

Comment: @txcotrader the code above is showing you how to change it after initialization.